# IIS6 isn't supported by powershell and upgrades cost money. Alternatives?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7, iis-6

As part of our .NET deployment process we'd like to make a new website on IIS. The idea is to be able to run another set of smoke tests before making a site live - plus being able to immediately roll back to a previous version should something go wrong. We hope to have this all hooked up to Jenkins.

While IIS7 has a comprehensive suite of tools that allows us to throw together and configure a new website via PowerShell, IIS6 shares no such luxury.

While upgrading to IIS7 would obviously solve our issues, our servers currently run on Windows 2003.

Is there a way to do what we want in IIS6? Are we going about the issue the wrong way?

Comment: If you need the tool, what's wrong with paying for it?

Comment: What about good old bat files?

Comment: @Tomas: Can you create and configure IIS website properties/virtual directors/etc via command line?

Comment: @JSWork You can do some of this http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/aee71684-36c0-40e1-b387-a19d2d0509f0.mspx?mfr=true, not sure about configuration...

Comment: @TomasVoracek: Please respond as an answer instead of a comment so i can click "mark as answer" and you can get appropriate credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS6 configuration is stored in 2 xml files, [MetaBase.xml and MSSchema.xml located in %SystemRoot%\System32\Inetsrv](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324277).

Check these links about available scripts for managing IIS sites, application pools etc:

- [Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17275)
- [Managing IIS Configurations Using Scripts (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1805162e-6ac5-4a98-9a08-919c4c10827d.mspx?mfr=true)
- [Administering Servers from the Command Line in IIS 6.0 (IIS 6.0)](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b3dd4a96-4b4d-4a49-926e-581f8bf081cd.mspx?mfr=true)
- [How to manage Web sites and Web virtual directories by using command-line scripts in IIS 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816568)

Regarding configuration of sites like default page, .NET version etc I couldn't find any script for that on Technet. But if it is in configuration xml, I think you can create some command line tool for that.